# count number of pages in a pdf file using python's pypdf2 library

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

what is the exact code to find the total number of pages in a PDF using Py2PDF library? The old method that is `.numPages` is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

using **.pages** method

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("US_Declaration.pdf")
readpdf = len(reader.pages)
```